# Writing code to enumerate all possible permutations of a given number of elements

Tags: logic

This question isn't so much about the syntax of code, but actually how i should go about creating a method.

When the program starts you enter a number for the amount of switches in the combination, each combination consists of how ever many switches that can have an on/off value. The program then goes through all the different combinations and prints the amount it could come up with.

The part I need help with is the nextCombination method. As of now I'm using a random generation of combination which results in inaccurate and inconsistent outputs for larger numbers. I would like to know how I would about creating a systematic method for doing this.

Heres an example of me inputting '2':

```
> Enter the length of the combination: 2
> FT
> FF
> TF
> TT
> Number of combinations: 4
```

here is the combination class:

```
public class Combination {

    private int number;

    private boolean[] values;

    public Combination(int number) {
        this.number = number;
        values = new boolean[number];
    }

    public Combination(boolean[] values) {
        this.number = values.length;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public void setValue(int i, boolean value) {
        values[i] = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Combination) {
            if (((Combination) o).number != number) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < ((Combination) o).number; i++) {
                if (values[i] != ((Combination) o).values[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (boolean b : values) {
            s = s + (b ? "T" : "F");
        }
        return s;
    }

}
```

Here's the Main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private final static int MAXIMUM_ATTEMPTS = 500;

    private static int attempts;

    private static int number;

    private static ArrayList<Combination> cache = new ArrayList<Combination>();

    private static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String... s) {
        System.out.print("Enter the length of the combination: ");
        number = myScanner.nextInt();
        Combination combination = nextCombination();
        while (combination != null) {
            if (!hasCombinationBeenUsed(combination)) {
                cache.add(combination);
                System.out.println(combination);
            }
            combination = nextCombination();
        }
        System.out.println("Number of combinations: " + Integer.toString(cache.size()));
    }

    private static Combination nextCombination() {
        boolean[] values = new boolean[number];
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            values[(int) (Math.random() * number)] = ((int) (Math.random() * (2))) == 1;
        }
        Combination combo = new Combination(values);
        if (!hasCombinationBeenUsed(combo)) {
            return combo;
        } else if (attempts < MAXIMUM_ATTEMPTS) {
            attempts++;
            return nextCombination();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasCombinationBeenUsed(Combination combo) {
        for (Combination c : cache) {
            if (c.equals(combo)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Any help with this is appreciated, and if you can make my code better/shorter/more efficient, then I would also like that too. Thanks :)

edit: I'm only 15, so I haven't gone to school for any of this so don't be too harsh

Comment: Maybe you could put some more descriptive title in the question...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are ready to learn about binary arithmetics! Think of a combination as a sequence of zeros and ones, representing a binary number. `TFF` represents 4, `TFT` is 5, and so on. Coming up with the next combination then is equivalent to incrementing the value - it is that simple!

With a little help of binary operations implemented in Java, C, C++, C# etc., you arrive at this code:

```
int size = 5;
for (int mask = 0 ; mask != (1 << size) ; mask++) {
    for (int i = size-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        System.out.print((mask & (1 << i)) == 0 ? 'F' : 'T');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Read a [page or two on bit operations](http://vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html), then play with this code [at ideone](http://ideone.com/9Y6za) to see how it works. I encourage you to make some parallels to the world of decimals, you will learn a lot about number systems in general!

Comment: Hmm, would you be able to give me a piece of code that I can just plug in? I will read up on this, I just don't know how I would begin to use it in this situation.

Comment: @connor Did you try the ideone page that I linked?

Comment: Ahh, no i didn't. I didn't realize that was all I needed to do this. Thanks a ton, this surely solved my problem :)